# ioredis - ERROR [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to connect to Elasticache Redis

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, ioredis

Can anybody help me with connecting to an Elasticache Redis Client using an AWS lambda?

I am using ioredis with below code to connect but I keep getting:

> ERROR [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT when
> trying to connect to Elasticache Redis

```
import Redis from "ioredis";

const connectionDetails = {
  host: "hostName",
  port: "port",
  tls: {}
};

const client = new Redis(connectionDetails);

export const getFromRedis = async (redisKey: string) => {
  const result = client.get(redisKey);
  console.log(result);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your configuration you have the right one. Below is my code for reference that I use to connect to ElastiCache, and it is same as yours.

```
this.redis = new IORedis({
    host: options.host,
    lazyConnect: false,
    port: options.port,
    tls: options.supportsTls ? {} : undefined,
    password: options.password ? options.password : undefined,
    connectTimeout: 10000,
});
```

So your issue most definitely is in the networking configuration.

- Ensure your Lambda is able to reach out to the subnet where Redis is hosted.
- Ensure Lambda Security Group allows egress to Redis, and Redis Security Group allows ingress from Lambda on the port specified in your Redis.
- Ensure your Lambda is attached to an `execution role` that gives it permission to call Redis.

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Other Considerations,

- Ensure you are not trying to connect to a cluster because that takes a few different parameters.
- Ensure the host and port you are trying to connect are correct.

Comment: To add on to this - 
Also make sure the Lambda is in the same VPC. 
Alternatively, if its in a different  VPC, you might want to check if VPC peering is enabled or perhaps there's a Transit Gateway connecting two VPCs.